# marquee infinite movement from right to left

Tags: html, marquee

I want to Create a Marquee with infinite movement

```
<marquee   direction="right"  behavior="alternate" scrollamount="3" class="qus"> <div id="divvv" ></div></marquee>
```

the above code is moving from left to right then right to left, but how i create infinite moving marquee from right to left, any idea

Comment: what is the use of `marquee`ing infinitely ?

Comment: `<marquee><font face="Comic sans MS" size="99">Look at me go!</font></marquee>`

Comment: @NickR Why you are using deprecated `font` tag?

Comment: @Mr.Alien It wasn't a serious comment.

Comment: @NickR Hehe please specify at the end like P.S - TROLL :p

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, which you are looking for,
Just check this plugin, it seems it's completing your requirements:

http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html

Don't waste your time, just click on the above link and enjoy :)